# Gateway Timeout error (504) on webapp even though i can see scraper is not done completing the fetch

Tags: node.js

google-ip-forwarding: Could not parse IP address: "local"."

This is the error I got in the GCE logs - I am running two applications - a webapp and a scraper. 
The error i'm facing comes in when i make a request from the webapp - I can see the scraper running to completion. However, the webapp doesn't wait for the scraper to complete the process and returns a gateway timeout (504) error within 30 seconds. Could someone please suggest where i might be missing something?

Moreover, it seems to be working all fine on local and returns results as expected. But carries out the aforementioned behaviour on production. Code included below:

```
exports.fetchNewShippingInfo = async (seller, pan, startDate, endDate ) => {
    return await axios.get(scraperServiceUrl+'/getShippingData', {
                params : {
                    iec_code : seller.iecCode,
                    count: 100,
                    pan_no : pan,
                    st_date : startDate,
                    end_date : endDate
                },
        }).then(async (response) => {
            console.log("Got successfully", response.data.results.data);
            let newData = JSON.parse(await response.data.results.data);
            for (var i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
                try {
                let shb_no = newData[i]['SHB No'];
                let temp_date = undefined;
                let bill_date = undefined;
                temp_date = newData[i]['SHB Date'].split('.').join('/');
                bill_date = moment(temp_date, 
                            "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM- 
                             DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
                let shipments = await Shipment.findOne({company : 
                                      seller, shippingBillNo : shb_no});
                    if(shipments){
                    shipments.data = refine_keys(newData[i]);
                    shipments.billId = undefined;
                    await shipments.save();
                    }
                    if(shipments == undefined){
                        let new_shipment = new Shipment({
                            company : seller, 
                            data : refine_keys(newData[i]),
                            billDate : bill_date,
                            shippingBillNo : newData[i]['SHB No']
                        })
                        console.log("Extracting data..");
                        await new_shipment.save();
                    }
                } catch (error){
                        console.log("Error: ", error);
                }
                }
                console.log("Extracted and Saved Data Successfully!");

        }).catch((error) => {
            if(error.response){
                console.log('Error Response: ', error.response);
            } else {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            }
        })
}
```

Where - the /getshippingData route leads to:

```
exports.shippingDetails = async (req,res) => {
    let iec_code = req.query.iec_code; 
    let pan_no = req.query.pan_no;
    let st_date = req.query.st_date;
    let end_date = req.query.end_date;
    let count = req.query.count;
    let model = await BrcModel.findOne({iecCode : iec_code});
    let newShippingData = undefined;
    let newData = await brcData(iec_code, count, pan_no, st_date, 
                  end_date);
    res.status(200).json(jsonHelper.getResponse("Success",null,{data : 
                                          JSON.stringify(newData)}));
  }
```

I can see the shippingDetails code run to completion in the log. With 'newData' being resolved - but fetch newShippingInfo doesn't wait for response and catches a 504 error after 30 seconds itself.

Comment: I think its a server issue, particularly timeout setting. Have you tried checking max_execution_time?

Comment: Yes, i tried checking that and changing it as well. Its set to 120 seconds right now - however the server is still returning a gateway error after 30 seconds.

Comment: without code it might be hard to debug

Comment: Have added the code - if it helps in debugging. I've tried setting several timeouts as well and that doesn't help.